# error related to sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to compile a model writte in fortran called pywofost. I followed the steps of compiling the model. however, I receive the following error related to sqlalchemy.exceptions. sqlalchemy version is '1.0.12'. the error message is as follows:

command

```
import pywofost
```

error

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/omar/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/omar/pywofost/pywofost.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.exceptions import *
ImportError: No module named exceptions
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no module in sqlalchemy named exceptions as of version 1.0.12. If you were depending on a third party module it looks like they have a bug in their code

There is `sqlalchemy.exc` or `sqlalchemy.orm.exc` if you want to import exceptions from there though. Maybe you can just modify the pywofost code quickly and continue your work?

Comment: @ Greg: I do not fully understand the suggestion. I understand that the version I am using (1.0.12) does not have the module exception. However, I do not understand the meaning of third party module (I am still new). Also, If i want to modify pywofost I wonder where and how to do so. shall I search for a certain command within the files !!!

Comment: Third party modules are software written by people who are not you. Also python has already told you where the bug is in the stacktrace: /home/omar/pywofost/pywofost.py . So you can just modify that code and hopefully everything will work

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc ledot /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/omar/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/omar/pywofost/pywofost.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .pyfortran.py_w60lib_wrapper import py_W60lib_wrapper
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by using older version of sqlalchemy